# Unable to match version using regex

Tags: regex, version

**Introduction**

**Aim:** to match version (2.4.0) located in sample using `ketarin`

*Regular expression:*

`(?=.*Release.*)[\d\.]+(?=.*available)`

Other digits are matcht as well according [Rubular](http://rubular.com/).

```
<a href="#News">News</a>
<ul class="minitoc">
<li>
<a href="#07+April%2C+2014%3A+Release+2.4.0+available">07 April, 2014: Release 2.4.0 available </a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#20+February%2C+2014%3A+Release+2.3.0+available">20 February, 2014: Release 2.3.0 available </a>
</li>
```

**Question**

How to match the version (2.4.0) from this text using regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do it like this?

```
/Release\+(\d\.\d\.\d)\+available/
```

Comment: According to Rubular this results in `Release+2.4.0+available`, while this regex works in ketarin. Thank you.

Comment: But it's got a capture group which matches `2.4.0` only. I can't tell you exactly how to get the string from the capture group, because you haven't told us which language you're using, but there should be some way of doing it, and it's the more common way than using lookarounds. My only objection to Severin's answer is that it doesn't match strings such as `Release+2.10.0+available` (where one of the numbers has two digits) but you can easily fix this by replacing `\d` with `\d+`.

Comment: @DavidKnipe A combination of Severin's and RayToal's answer: `Release\+([\d.]+)\+available` works in ketarin. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You were close; the first part should have been a lookbehind, not a lookahead.

```
/(?<=Release )[\d.]+(?= available)/
```

worked for me: http://rubular.com/r/VuYVl9xMum

Change the spaces to your needs.  Also note that the regex allows things like `34.....3.1.....` so consider

```
\d+(\.\d+)*
```

for version numbering.

UPDATE: A new version, using this version number pattern, at http://rubular.com/r/H4hIDKZz2V

Comment: This works in Rubular while this is not the case in ketarin. Thank you.